# Customise soap fault message for a web service

Tags: java, web-services

I am creating a webservice and would like to customize the messages which contract is returning. For example, if I put a String value to an integer attribute I will receive this default fault:

```
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: For input string: "teste"</faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
```

How could I add the name of the element that generated this error? or customise this message? I created a @ Webfault but was unable to get the name of the element and this cause, it no call my Webfault.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "ReceberPedido", portName = "ReceberPedidoSOAP", endpointInterface = "br.com.shapeness.service.ReceberPedidoPortType", targetNamespace = "http://www.teste.com.br/ReceberPedidoService")
@Stateless
public class ReceberPedidoWS {

    @EJB
    HistoricoProcessamentoRepository repository;

    public ReceberPedidoResponse receberPedido(ReceberPedidoRequest parameters) throws ReceberPedidoFault {
        try{

            List<String> erros = verificaParametros(parameters);

            repository.saveOrUpdate(new HistoricoProcessamento());

            return null;
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new ReceberPedidoFault(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


@WebService(name = "ReceberPedidoPortType", targetNamespace = "http://www.teste.com.br/ReceberPedidoService")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
//@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC, use = Use.LITERAL)
public interface ReceberPedidoPortType {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "ReceberPedido", action = "http://www.teste.com.br/ReceberPedidoService/ReceberPedido")
    @RequestWrapper(targetNamespace="http://www.teste.com.br/ReceberPedidoService", className="java.lang.String")
    @ResponseWrapper(targetNamespace="http://www.teste.com.br/ReceberPedidoService", className="org.teste.ReceberPedidoResponseWrapper")
    @WebResult(name = "ReceberPedidoResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.teste.com.br/ReceberPedidoService", partName = "parameters")
    public ReceberPedidoResponse receberPedido(
        @WebParam(name = "ReceberPedidoRequest", targetNamespace = "http://www.teste.com.br/ReceberPedidoService", partName = "parameters")
        ReceberPedidoRequest parameters) throws ReceberPedidoFault;

}

WebFault(name = "ReceberPedidoFault", targetNamespace = "http://www.teste.com.br/ReceberPedidoService")
public class ReceberPedidoFault extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ReceberPedidoFaultBean faultInfo;

    public ReceberPedidoFault(ReceberPedidoFaultBean faultInfo) {
        super(faultInfo.getMessage());
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public ReceberPedidoFault(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ReceberPedidoFault(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public ReceberPedidoFault(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public ReceberPedidoFault(String message, ReceberPedidoFaultBean faultInfo) {
        super(message);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public ReceberPedidoFault(String message, ReceberPedidoFaultBean faultInfo, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public ReceberPedidoFaultBean getFaultInfo() {
        return faultInfo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code that is producing that error. Usually this message will be generated by an exception that is thrown by your code and catched by the framework you are using for your web service.

Comment: Hi @Matthias, you are correct, but, in this case, the framework is own JEE, cause i using `@webservice`. To place the call to service, xml'm forcing the error and in this case it does not come to my treatment, the framework already own the problem returns marshal.